# 18.04 apt-get install python3-netcdf4

Tags: package-management, python3

When trying to install the package `python3-netcdf4`, I get the error

```
E:  Unable to locate package python3-netcdf4
```

I have tried to update, but the package is not found.
Where do I find it?

```
apt-cache policy python3-netcdf4 
   python3-netcdf4: 
      Installed: (none) 
      Candidate: 1.3.1-1 
      Version table: 
        1.3.1-1 500 500 us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Comment: Universe already enabled

Comment: Then run `sudo apt-get update` and add output of `apt-cache policy python3-netcdf4` to the question.

Comment: apt-cache policy python3-netcdf4
python3-netcdf4:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.3.1-1
  Version table:
     1.3.1-1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages

Comment: Add output of `sudo apt-get install python3-netcdf4=1.3.1-1` to the question text.

Comment: If `apt policy` finds it, it should be found when you `apt install` it. Have you re-tried? Might you have made a typo?

Answer (score 0):

Change directories to your desktop, download python3-netcdf4, and install it. Open the terminal and type:

```
cd ~/Desktop/
apt download python3-netcdf4  
sudo apt-get install ./python3-netcdf4_1.3.1-1_amd64.deb
```